# Golang slow when looping over Collection

Tags: go

Im feeding my app a json from Redis which I then unmarshal and loop through.

Here is what the json Im feeding from Redis looks like:

```
[
    {
        "titel": "test 1",
        "event": "some value",
        "pair": "some value",
        "condition": [
            "or",
            [
                "contains",
                "url",
                "/"
            ],[
                "notcontains",
                "url",
                "hello"
            ]
        ],
        "actions": [
            [
                "option1",
                "12",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "option2",
                "3",
                "1"
            ]
        ]
    }, {
        "titel": "test 2",
        "event": "some value",
        "pair": "some value",
        "condition": [
            "or",
            [
                "contains",
                "url",
                "/"
            ]
        ],
        "actions": [
            [
                "option1",
                "12",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "option2",
                "3",
                "1"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

My struct to store the json looks like this:

```
type Trigger struct {
    Event     string        `json:"event"`  
    Pair      string        `json:"pair"`   
    Actions   [][]string    `json:"actions"`
    Condition Condition     `json:"condition"`
}

type Condition []interface{}

func (c *Condition) Typ() string {
    return (*c)[0].(string)
}

func (c *Condition) Val() []string {
    xs := (*c)[1].([]interface{})
    ys := make([]string, len(xs))
    for i, x := range xs {
        ys[i] = x.(string)
    }
    return ys
}

func (c *Condition) String() (string, string, string) {
    return c.Val()[0], c.Val()[1], c.Val()[2]
}

type Triggers struct {
    Collection []Trigger
}
```

And Im unmarshaling it into the struct like so:

```
var triggers Triggers
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(triggersJson), &triggers.Collection)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error while unmarshaling triggers json: ", err)
}
```

This works and performs perfectly fine while testing it with siege.
However, as soon as I want to start loop over the struct Im starting to see long response times and timeouts.

This is how I loop over it:

```
for _,element := range triggers.Collection {
    if element.Event == "some value" {
        fmt.Println("We got: some value")
    }
 }
```

Performance without the loop is 2ms on 500 concurrent connections.
With the loop its 600ihs ms on 500 concurrent with a bunch of timeouts

Ideally Id like to change structure of the json to not include:

```
"or",
```

But Im not in control over the json so this is unfortunately impossible.

Any ideas whats causing this and how it could be resolved?

**Edit**

I found whats slowing the whole thing down.

Editing my struct like:

```
type Trigger struct {
    Event     string        `json:"event"`  
    Pair      string        `json:"pair"`   
    Actions   [][]string    `json:"actions"`
    //Condition Condition     `json:"condition"`
}
```

Takes it from 600ms to 100ms. However now Im not able to parse the `Condition`.

Now sure how to parse the Condition in another way than Im currently doing due it having two different formats

Comment: Typically there is 4-50 in the collection

Comment: A loop comparing 4-50 strings will not increase executation from 2ms to 600ms.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Profile your code and see what is blocking. You haven't shown enough here to indicate a problem.

Comment: Are you actually printing something? That will certainly slow things down considerably

Comment: See edit :) Found whats slowing it down

Comment: You're re-parsing `Condition` 3 full times every time you call its String method. Copy it the values once into another field of the correct type, or better yet, do it during Unamrshal to remove these extra methods altogether.

Comment: @JimB not sure I follow exactly

Comment: Every time `Condition.String()` is called, you call `Val` 3 more times, allocating slices and copying the values in, and then you throw it all away. At a minimum, call `Val` once for `String`, but it would be better to not allocated the extra slice every time to begin with. This is a problem, but it might not be your only problem. Either profile the code, or post a reproducible example.

Comment: You definitely should memorize `Condition.Val()` result if performance is your concern here. But I don't see where `Condition.String()` is called and how this can affect this particular loop...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds weird, but try to avoid copying Collection elements. Something like this:

```
for i := range triggers.Collection {
    if triggers.Collection[i].Event == "some value" {
        fmt.Println("We got: some value")
    }
```